# Java, Get all classes available to a URLClassLoader that implement a specific interface

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, serviceloader

I am working on a command line app that loads user specified text translators at runtime (path to class files/jar provided via command line arg). Basically I am taking that argument and using it to create a URLClassLoader. Then I need to find all classes available to the URLClassloader that implement the Transable interface.

Right now I am only allowing this command line arg to be a directory with class files in it. Making the solution fairly simple (code below). But honestly I don't like the solution as it breaks down for jar files, directory of jar files, etc... Also, this obviously breaks down for any classes with a defined package, as loadClass needs the full name including the package. Anyone have a better method?

```
    File d = new File(path);
    if(d.isDirectory()) {
        URL url = d.toURI().toURL();
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});

        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".class");
            }
        };

        for(File f : d.listFiles(filter)) {
            String name = f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().indexOf("."));
            String key = "";
            if(name.endsWith("Translator")) {
                key = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("Translator"));
            }
            else if(name.endsWith("translator")) {
                key = name.substring(0, name.indexOf("translator"));
            }
            else
                key = name;

            Class c = cl.loadClass(name);
            if(Transable.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                Transable t = (Transable)c.newInstance();
                env.registerTranslator(key, t);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("[ClassLoader] "+c.getCanonicalName()+" will not be loaded. It is not a translator class");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }
```

Comment: just go in the jar file and check all entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just have to brute force it if you continue down this road. To my knowledge the default class loader will not even load a class into the JVM unless it is referenced somehow. Which means, some of your classes will be basically invisible unless you know their fully qualified class name to load them.

You may want to reconsider your requirements. As it would be far easier to load a set of Translators that you have been given the class names for.

Comment: I am considering moving some of this off to a config file that would require explicit names, or at least the name of the package containing the translator classes. Its a better approach, I just want to make sure the the other option can't be implemented cleanly first.

Comment: @jdc0589 There are solutions for jars and local files, but AFAIK not a generic one for any kind of classloader.

Comment: care to elaborate? I am only concerned with local files and local jars

Comment: Changed the format of my input files to require explicit definition of translator classes. Definitely the best option.

Answer (score 3):

This may fit the bill.  If not, you ought to be able to look through their source to get an idea of what will work for you. http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Comment: Looks really interesting..but can you say dependency HELL?

Comment: I just saw a reference to it earlier in the day and then stumbled on your question so thought I would pass it along.  I've never used it, but thought if nothing else, you could look through the source and see what they are doing.

Answer (score 3):

In principle this can't work for arbitrary classloaders, as they may use any way imaginable to actually load the classes, and not have any "directory listening" function at all.

A classloader might even generate classes (i.e. the bytecode for the classes) on the fly whenever a `loadClass` comes, and imagine a TransableClassloader where each such automatically defined class would implement your interface - your program would never end.

---

That said, for an `URLClassloader` you can use `getURLs()`, and for the `jar:` and `file:` URL you can use the `JarFile` or `File` api to get the list of filenames (and thus Classnames) to try. As you have the root of your package hierarchy given in the URL, finding the right package name is not difficult, too.

(If you need more details, say it.)

---

*Edit:* For the package names, they correspond to the directory names inside of your hierarchy. So, when you have a base URL which corresponds to (say) `dir/classes`, and find a class-file named `dir/classes/com/company/gui/SimpleTranslator.class`, it corresponds to class `com.company.gui.SimpleTranslator`.

So, remove the base prefix and replace `/` by `.` (and cut of the `.class`). (In a JarFile you don't have to cut a prefix off.)

Actually, if you use a recursive method to traverse your File hierarchy, you can build up your package-name with the same method, simply by appending Strings (give them as a parameter to the next recursive Invocation):

```
public void searchClassesInDir(File dir, String packagePrefix) {
    if(dir.isDirectory()) {
        String prefix = packagePrefix + dir.getName() + ".";
        for(File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            searchClasses(f, prefix);
        }
    }
    else {
       String fileName = dir.getName();
       if(! fileName.endsWith(".class"))
           return;
       String className = packagePrefix + fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-".class".length());
       // now do the rest of your processing
    }
}

searchClasses(new File(url.toURI()), "");
```

Comment: I think this is the path I will take. I know how to do everything aside from determining package names. The only method I can think of is to just get the path of the class entry in the jar file, replace the file separators with a '.' and chop the '.class' off the end. There another way?

Comment: I added an example here. But chopping off the '.class' and converting '/' to '.' works too.

Comment: You can also add your filter to the `listFiles()` call, but make sure it catches subdirectories, too (or in a second loop). For a jar file this works similar, I think, you just need to traverse the `JarEntry`s (and don't need recursion, instead the replacement).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of searching for implementors explicitly, you should uss Java's Service Provider Interface (SPI) and the [ServiceLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class (introduced in Java 6).  SPI is a pretty much a standard way to do what you are describing in Java.

Please see the [official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) on how to create a service provider and how to use it, at runtime, with ServiceLoader.

Comment: Sounds awesome, will take a look asap. Thanks

Comment: A little confused here. Maybe I just havent found it yet..but it seems like this only returns the default implementations defined in my META-INF/services/org.jextend.Transable file? At least thats all I can get it to do now, even though I constructed the ServiceLoader with class loader argument that has access to other implementations.

Comment: Found this text in the link you posted:"Also, the current ServiceLoader class can't tell your application when new providers are available at runtime." Whats the deal?

Comment: There could be multiple META-INF/services/org.jextend.Transable files in different root directories or jar files found by your classloader(s). There is also a tool to help you create those files during build: http://code.google.com/p/spi/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: The deal with not discovering new providers during runtime is that the ServiceLoader will look for and parse the service description files during startup, so when you put a new file and service implementation class in your classpath while your program is running, it won't be picked up right away but only after you restart your program.

Comment: This really is the standard way to do things now. I know its an old question, but I think it bears mentioning for other people reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

Since Class c = cl.loadClass(name);

Class method getInterfaces() returns an array of classes

Check each class name for match to translator class name.

Comment: That is not really the issue. Thanks though